# CSS - How to make different background color from css file used

Tags: html, css

I dont know if my quest below is a simple thing.
I just imported a css to the page, then this is change the background color. how do I make the background color to the original (say white). I know this can be done by changing the contents of the css file, but in the css file contained many tough row I inspect one by one.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
<link href="../assets/imgbanner.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <style> body {background-color:white;} </style>
```

Comment: You should show some code if you want help.

Comment: Please provide some code. Are you trying to override styles in an external style sheet with inline or in-page styles?

Comment: use Inspect element if you have Chrome

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, you are saying that you imported a css which changed the background color of your page and you want to turn it back without changing the css?  Wouldn't it be simpler to just remove that line of code?  In your css file just look for a "background-color" and comment it out.

Comment: i have update my post. i have to add inline css too, but it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to "force" a certain value for a property use the `!important` keyword after the value:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SomeCss.css" />

<style type="text/css">
    body{ background: white!important; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well...you could do a search for the background color and/or tags and just replace them.  You do shouldn't have to actually look through the whole file by hand.

CSS is Cascading, as the name would indicate.  Just create a new style on your page or new CSS file that overrides the value from your imported file with the value you want.  Just make sure to reference your new file after the one you just imported.

Comment: actually i have think like you. but there is much color code, i have try to replace all color beside 'background-color' to #ffffff.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way would be to just stick it in your HTML in the line *directly below* the line where you import this buggered CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StupidCSSWithStupidBackground.css" /> 
<style> body {background-color:white;} </style>
```

Alternately, stick that `{background-color:white;}` in another CSS file, and link to it in the second line.

Comment: i have update my post. i have to add inline css too, but it failed.

Comment: Maybe try `html {background-color:white;}` instead? Though I don't think that would help.